# Extend div if child is more than 100%

Tags: html, css

Trying to make `header`'s width same as `content` intrinsically since `div`s should occupy full width.

Have tried applying `overflow:auto` to `html,body,header`

https://codesandbox.io/s/xrn9q6ojxw

```
<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style>
        header {
            display:block;
            background: blue;
        }

        .content {
            width: 2000px;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <header>header</header>
    <div class="content">content</div>

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Expect to scroll entire page horizontally and `header`'s width to be the same as `content`'s or `body`'s.

Is it possible to have `header` or `div` blocks extend beyond viewport's width without specifying a width explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a wrapping div for both header and content and style it as below. Hope this is you are looking for.

```css
.wrapper{
  float:left
}
header {
  display:block;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  width: 2000px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>header</header>
 <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I can also float the `body` thus saving one container.

Comment: @hackerl33t float is a hacky solution, use `inline-block` instead

Comment: @hackerl33t, you may use .wrapper{ display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 0):

Try out this and tell me if this is what you are looking for.

CSS

```
#scroller {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;  
  background-color: red; 
}

#scroller-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
}


.elem {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scroller-wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
        <div class="elem">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="elem">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="elem">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This will basically give you infinite horizontal scroll depending on the content.